# Android - How can prevent app run automatically when filter ACTION_SEND to have only one app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-sharing

In my app, I use ACTION_SEND intent in purpose for sharing some text. However, I customize this ACTION_SEND filtering for three apps like Twitter, Facebook and KakaoStory. It doesn't have problem when I have at least two of these apps installed in my phone; It shows a dialog with two installed apps to choose. However, when I have only one app installed in my phone when I click share it doesn't show a dialog for choosing app, it launched that app automatically. How can I prevent this. I want it to show dialog first and then I can choose it even though it has only on app.

Comment: Why?  If they're only going to have 1 choice, the extra step is just annoying.  That's a bad user experience.

Comment: No, they are going to have 3 choice, but they have only one choice installed in phone.

Comment: Right.  But since they don't have the others installed on the phone, they can't choose the other two anyway.  So why make them take an extra step?

Comment: How did u manage to filter the send intent?

Answer (score 1):

If there have only one choice, The android system will choice it. I think you can't change this unless you change the android source code.